# Fitting an envelope

Tags: python, regression

I want to have a fit for the following classic problem:

[image]

Where alpha is some continuous envelope that I want to estimate.

In specific I have two signals, one with noise and want to recover the amplitude information, especially the attack envelope for the reconstructed signal, which I know to be exponentialish shape. However, the amplitudes may also vary elsewhere, so there may be better solutions than a simple exponential fit with variable start time.

Are there ready made solutions in python for this kind of problem, preferably with pythonic syntax. Can the spline regressions in Scipy be somehow used on multivariable problems or are they just for interpolation?